# How to create combination of 3 distinct requests to work together

Tags: c#, sql, distinct

I will try to explain it visually:

table consists of

- brand
- model
- version
- type
- color

the logic of search is:

1. choose brand, **enable** filter model - 1st tier
2. choose model, **enable** filters version & type & color - 2nd tier
3. choose any filter = version or type or color - 3rd tier, these are distict selects

how to create logic that if I choose distinct version then select creates query where brand=@brand, model=@model, version=@version. And I need to create distinct type and distinct color if available based on previous query.

It would be quite easy if there was defined logic like 1. brand, 2. model, 3. version, 4. type, 5. color.

But I need to create logic where I can choose 1.brand, 2.model, 3.color and version & type will amend for that query.

Is there a good way to do this within SQL or C# ?

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sounds like you just need to use C# to dynamically build your SQL query based on what filters were selected.

Answer (score 0):

Supporting an unknown number of params in a "Search" can be done in a stored proc by checking if the parameter is supplied

```
CREATE PROC SomeSearch
  @param1 VARCHAR(10) = NULL,
  @param2 INT = NULL
  -- etc
AS
SELECT whatever
FROM MyTable
WHERE
  (@param1 IS NULL OR field1=@param1)
  AND (@param2 IS NULL OR field2=@param2)
-- etc
```

Now just pass NULL (or dont pass the param at all - the default is NULL) when that particular filter is not required.

Comment: but the way I understand the question, the OP is looking for the distinct of the other two values if three are selected.